# Why does an algebraic curve over an algebraic closed field have smooth points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is there an easy way to see this fact? I could try to show that the differential of the defining polynomial cannot vanish at all the zeros. However, I don't see how this could be done. Also there should be a more sophisticated way.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is as follows. We can assume without loss of generality that $f$ is non-zero and irreducible.

If $f$ was not smooth anywhere, then $f_{x_i}$ vanishes everywhere on $f$ and so each $f_{x_i}$ would be divisible by $f$. By degree considerations this implies that each $f_{x_i}$ is zero. Clearly this is impossible in characteristic zero (why?), and so we may assume that our field has characteristic $p$. Then, each $f_{x_i}$ being zero implies that $f$ is actually of the for $g(x_1^p,\ldots,x_n^p)$, and since the coefficients are also $p^{\text{th}}$-powers this implies that $f=g^p$, which contradicts that $f$ is irreducible.

**EDIT:** I assumed you meant plane curve, for some reason, in the above. You can make the above work for any variety though (after this edit) by first assuming that we're working with a hypersurface in some projective space. This is ok since any variety is birational to a hyperurface in some projective space.

Answer (score 5):

This one of the things which become trivial in scheme language, i.e. if we also include the generic point $\eta$ to our curve. Then $\Omega^1_{X,\eta}$ is free of rank $1$, hence $\Omega^1$ is free of rank $1$ in a neighborhood of $\eta$. It contains a closed point, done.